# Python3: What is the difference between keywords and builtins?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3,

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
```

and

```
>>> import builtins
>>> dir(builtins)
```

are two different lists, yet they have some common values, specifically

```
>>> set(dir(builtins)) & set(keyword.kwlist)
{'False', 'True', 'None'}
```

What is the difference of keywords and builtins in python? and when are `'False', 'None', 'True'` keywords and when are they builtins? (if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Keywords are core language constructs handled by the parser.  These words are reserved and cannot be used as identifiers: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Builtins are a list of commonly used, preloaded functions, constants, types, and exceptions:  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html

In Python 3, the overlapping words, *False*, *None*, and *True* are builtin constants that are protected from assignment by the parser.  This prevents accidental overwriting with something like `True=10`.  As a keyword, this assignment can be blocked:

```
>>> True = 10
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
```

The remaining builtins are not protected and could be reassigned with something like `__builtins__.list = mylist`.

Comment: +1, but why are `False`, `True` and `None` keywords? The only reason that I can come up with is that you can't assign to them this way, but why would that be forbidden?

Comment: Blocking assignment to True, False, and None allows the code generator to treat these as real constants rather than variables.  It allows faster code to be generated, it lets people writing code treat them as singletons (*is* tests instead of == tests), and it helps people reading code because they know True/False/None always mean True/False/None.  Of course, the real reason they are keywords is that Guido wanted it that way :-)

Comment: @larsmans: How would you define the semantics of control constructs and boolean expressions in the face of redefining true and false?

Comment: @Inerdia: I'm not saying I actually want to reset any of these. I was just wondering why I'm not allowed to in a language that allows lots of other things that don't immediately make sense. Raymond's explanation is convincing enough.

Comment: Also, at least in Python 2.7, it seems like you can do `__builtins__.True = 123`. (May the FSM have mercy on our souls.)

Comment: @larsmans: The point I was trying to lead to is that allowing their redefinition in a reasonable and consistent fashion in the name of flexibility would likely be far more work than just forbidding it.

Comment: @Inerdia: I'm not familiar enough with the Python compiler to know which option would be harder to implement.

Comment: Historically Python allowed `True=0` but it was decided that speed is better than flexibility in this case as there is no conceivable use case for `True=0`.

Comment: @yak Since I only have a python3 interpreter at hand and asking is free - what was the consequence wrt something like `True = 0;x = 0; if x: #stuff`?  I.e. was `if x` hard coded or did it do a test against true? Actually I'm not sure which case would be more horrible..