# Why does assignment to int and float are not generating error whereas assignment to while does generate error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, assignment-operator

### Source:

```
int = 33

float = 0.0

while = 33
```

### Output:

```
while = 33
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does assignment to **int** and **float** are not generating error in  python whereas assignment to while generates error?

Comment: `while` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). `int` and `float` are [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). Different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3: What is the difference between keywords and builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204542/python3-what-is-the-difference-between-keywords-and-builtins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while` is a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). Keywords are essential parts of the language that cannot be used as variable names.

`int` and `float` are [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). That means they already essentially are variable names, but they are automatically assigned to standard parts of the library for you to use. However, that does not prevent you setting them to something else.

NB Though you can do it, it is generally inadvisable to set the names of built-ins to something else, because it leads to unclear code and confusing bugs.